# Systemd timer triggers only once

Tags: systemd, systemd-timer

My systemd timer is configured to run ever day at 3:00.

The timer gets triggered only on the first day at 3:00 and `systemd list-timers` says `n/a` in the `Left` or `Next` column.

**borgbackup.timer:**

```
[Unit]
Description=Run Borgbackup daily

[Timer]
OnCalendar=03:00:00
Unit=borgbackup.target

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

**borgbackup.target**

```
[Unit]
Description=Borgbackup group target
Wants=borgbackup-1.service borgbackup-2.service

[Install]
Also=borgbackup.timer
```

**borgbackup-1.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=Daily Borgbackup
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
Environment=BORG_PASSPHRASE="..."
Environment=BORG_BASE_DIR="/home/borg"
Environment=BORG_REPO="..."
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c "/usr/bin/borg create ::$(date --iso-8601) ..."
ExecStopPost=/usr/bin/borg prune -s -d 1 -w 1 -m 1
WorkingDirectory=/home/borg

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

The only difference between borgbackup-1 and borgbackup-2 is the repository.

Comment: AFAICT a target unit doesn't stop when the services it triggered do. And starting an already active unit seems to do nothing. Is there something in your setup meant to stop `borgbackup.target`?

Comment: That was indeed the issue. Adding StopWhenUnneeded=yes solved the issue, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The `OnCalendar` needs to be changed right now it reads the next time 3:00 occurs you need to add day of the week, month, etc.. You can also just change it to `Daily` the syntax for the way you have it would be `*-*-* 3:00:00`  There is a good section in this link about it.

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd/Timers#Timer_units

EDIT:  You probably also want to look into the `persistent` option it will run the command the next time the system is booted if the last time it was supposed to run was missed.